# Punctuating a quote of multiple answers

Tags: punctuation, speech

Consider the following:

'The lecturer asked the students a question. A chorus of "yes"es was heard.'

I know that the second sentence is incorrectly punctuated, but am not sure how to sort it out. How should a quote of multiple answers be expressed?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not a quote:  *A* *chorus* *of* yeses.  A quote would be *The students answered in a chorus, "Yes."*

Answer (score 1):

First, you wouldn't put quotes around "yes."  You would merely say, "A chorus of yeses was heard."

Second, the rules for citing [a quote within quotes](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/quotes.asp) varies by style and varies between the UK an the US.  However, unlike many other languages that increase the number of marks from single, to double, to triple, etc., the standard for English is fairly consistent in that we alternate between single quotation marks and double quotation marks.

If the style you are using requires the outer quotations marks be single, then use double quotation marks for the interior quote:

> Jane said, 'John said, "No." '

If it requires the outer quotations marks be double, then use single quotation marks for the interior quote:

> Jane said, "John said, 'No.' "

If you have more than one quote embedded in a quote, then you repeat the pattern:

> Jane said, "John said, 'Paul said, "No." ' "

It should be noted that when quotations marks come next to each other, the rule is to insert a space between them so as to be able to distinguish between them and not create some bizarre triple, quadruple or, in the last example above, quintuple quotation mark.